# Counting the number of times one level of a variable occurs using dplyr, group_by and summarise in r

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, factors

I want to summarise both factor and numerical variables using group_by and summarise. For example, if I have the following data frame:

```
group<- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
var1<- c(3, 6, 3, 2, 7, 5, 2, 5)
var2<- c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A")

df<- data.frame(group, var1, var2)
```

I want to achieve the following output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
group max_1 sum_A
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6       1
2     3       0
3     7       2
4     5       1
```

I have tried various iterations of the following using "tally", and "n", and "sum", but none work

```
summary<- df %>% group_by (group) %>%
                summarise(max_1 = max(var1)),
                            mutate (var2A = sum (var2 == "A"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code had a typo `max(var1)` the `)` is extra.  If you remove that, it should return the expected

Comment: Then I get the following error: Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..2`.
i `..2 = mutate(var2A = sum(var2 == "A"))`.
x no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
i The error occurred in group 1: group = 1.

Comment: Based on your input, this works `df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(max_1 = max(var1), sum_A = sum(var2 == 'A'))
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  group max_1 sum_A
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     6     1
2     2     3     0
3     3     7     2
4     4     5     1`

Comment: You can't call `mutate` inside `summarise`. Just remove the `mutate` call